# How to show round figure number in php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a variable called `$totalResults` which has dynamic values, depend on database entries. I need to show a limit like if `$totalResults` has `154` results then I want  show that 154 out of 500. But I want it dynamically, like if the result cross 500, example the result value is 514, then it'll show like 514 out of 1000.

I don't want to use if, else conditions because the result will gradually increase, so i need to compare it dynamically, Like if result has 1500 entries, then I'll add +500 into it, Then it'll show Like 1500 out of 2000.

I am confused in this part, If the result is not round figure, how can I make it right?

My Logic:

```
$totalResult = 154;
$newResult = $totalResult + 500;

//Result = 654
But I want to show this 154 out of 500 or 154 out of 1000
```

Comment: *"like if `$totalResults` has `154` results then I want show that 154 out of 500..."* it's clear that `154` is the `$totalResults` what i can't understand is what `500` is ? where does it come from ?

Comment: As for now it's manually inputed, But what i want is Whatever value ```$totalResult``` has I want the round figure for ```out of``` value.

Example: 
Result is 280, Then show: 280 out of 500,
Result is 560, Then show: 560 out of 1000,
Result is 1056, Then show: 1056 out of 1500

Comment: so basically you add 500 to the total ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ceil` function

```
$totalResult = 154;
$coparisonQuotient = ceil($totalresults / 500);
$outOf = $comparisonQuotient * 500;

echo $totalResult . " out of " . $outOf;
```

Now, if the total results are 154, it would display `154 out of 500`

If it is above 500, but less than 1000, let's say 784. It will display `784 out of 1000`